# Printing out a list of pointers

Tags: c++, list, pointers

I currently have created a List of pointers that point to every 5th element of another List of ints. I am trying to print out this list of pointer to ensure that it is pointing to the right elements of the other list.

I've tried various ways to do this but none of them seem to work.

```
for (int* t = pointersList.begin(); t != pointersList.end(); ++t)
{
   cout << *t << endl;
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < pointersList.size(); ++i)
{
   int* itr;
   itr = pointersList.begin()+i;
   cout << *itr;
}
```

I also tried accesssing it like a vector (`cout << pointersList[i];`) but none of these seem to work.

I understand that a pointer points to the memory location of an element (and that's where I use the `*`) but I never know when I am suppose to use a `&` or even `&*`.

Comment: Are you perhaps saying "list" when you want to say "array"? Not the same. List usually means linked list

Comment: Also please don't say "doesn't seem to work", that doesn't give any information

Comment: Probably best to start reading a good C++ book if those basics aren't clear to you yet. Pay specific attention to "iterators" when you get to that chapter.

Comment: are you sure this is list? 0_o

Comment: @Mr.Anubis Yes I am I can show you the implementaion of it if you wish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the Following. This should work. This will get it to print your values of your pointers. Hope this is what you were looking for.

```
for(int a = 0; a < pointersList.size(); a ++)
   {
    std::list<int*>::iterator i = pointersList.begin();

    advance(i, a);
    int* totry = *i;
    cout << *totry;
    cout << ",";
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you're using a standard library container or one with a similar interface, then `begin()` and `end()` return iterators, not int*. In most cases, the code as is shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

You are having a serious problem in here. I just give you some hint hoping you find the answer in 10 minutes yourself.

In the first for loop you are increasing the pointer itself instead of the list.